# How to use WebView with Picasso?

Tags: android, webview, picasso

In my case, i used WebView to render and display news details, and i want to handle news images downloading and caching by myself instead of WebView. so i used Picasso for my images lib like below:

```
@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB)
@Override
public WebResourceResponse shouldInterceptRequest(WebView view, String url) {
    if (!Utils.hasHoneycomb()||TextUtils.isEmpty(url)||url.startsWith("file://")) {
        return super.shouldInterceptRequest(view, url);
    }
    if (!url.startsWith("http") || !url.endsWith(".jpg") || !url.endsWith(".jpeg") || !url.endsWith(".png") ) {
        return super.shouldInterceptRequest(view, url);
    }

    WebResourceResponse response = null;
    try {
        final PipedOutputStream out = new PipedOutputStream();
        PipedInputStream in = new PipedInputStream(out);

        Picasso.with(Application.getInstance()).load(url).into(new Target() {
            @Override
            public void onBitmapLoaded(Bitmap bitmap, Picasso.LoadedFrom from) {
                if (bitmap != null) {
                    try {
                        out.write(StreamTool.bmp2ByteArray100(bitmap, false));
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    } finally {
                        try {
                            out.close();
                        } catch (IOException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onBitmapFailed(Drawable errorDrawable) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onPrepareLoad(Drawable placeHolderDrawable) {

            }
        });
        response = new WebResourceResponse("image/*", "UTF-8", in);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return response;
}
```

but it doesn't work,  and i know **shouldInterceptRequest** works in non-UI thread, Picassso

```
throw new IllegalStateException("Method call should happen from the main thread.");
```

so i have two questions:

1. What's the general way to handle image downloading and caching by ourselves instead of WebView?
2. How to use Picasso off the main thread?

**UPDATED (adding Exception stack)：**

```html
06-08 18:17:05.540    5137-6951/com.news.daily I/dalvikvm﹕ java.lang.IllegalStateException: Method call should happen from the main thread.
06-08 18:17:05.540    5137-6951/com.news.daily I/dalvikvm﹕ at com.squareup.picasso.Utils.checkMain(Utils.java:136)
06-08 18:17:05.540    5137-6951/com.news.daily I/dalvikvm﹕ at com.squareup.picasso.RequestCreator.into(RequestCreator.java:496)
06-08 18:17:05.540    5137-6951/com.news.daily I/dalvikvm﹕ at com.news.daily.widget.webview.WebViewClientDaily.shouldInterceptRequest(WebViewClientDaily.java:123)
06-08 18:17:05.550    5137-6951/com.news.daily I/dalvikvm﹕ at android.webkit.CallbackProxy.shouldInterceptRequest(CallbackProxy.java:1534)
06-08 18:17:05.550    5137-6951/com.news.daily I/dalvikvm﹕ at android.webkit.BrowserFrame.shouldInterceptRequest(BrowserFrame.java:972)
06-08 18:17:05.550    5137-6951/com.news.daily I/dalvikvm﹕ at android.webkit.WebSettingsClassic.nativeSync(Native Method)
06-08 18:17:05.550    5137-6951/com.news.daily I/dalvikvm﹕ at android.webkit.WebSettingsClassic.access$100(WebSettingsClassic.java:50)
06-08 18:17:05.550    5137-6951/com.news.daily I/dalvikvm﹕ at android.webkit.WebSettingsClassic$EventHandler$1.handleMessage(WebSettingsClassic.java:291)
06-08 18:17:05.550    5137-6951/com.news.daily I/dalvikvm﹕ at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
06-08 18:17:05.550    5137-6951/com.news.daily I/dalvikvm﹕ at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
06-08 18:17:05.550    5137-6951/com.news.daily I/dalvikvm﹕ at android.webkit.WebViewCore$WebCoreThread.run(WebViewCore.java:1092)
06-08 18:17:05.550    5137-6951/com.news.daily I/dalvikvm﹕ at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
06-08 18:17:05.550    5137-6951/com.news.daily I/dalvikvm﹕ DALVIK THREADS:
06-08 18:17:05.550    5137-6951/com.news.daily I/dalvikvm﹕ (mutexes: tll=0 tsl=0 tscl=0 ghl=0)
06-08 18:17:05.550    5137-6951/com.news.daily I/dalvikvm﹕ "main" prio=5 tid=1 NATIVE
06-08 18:17:05.550    5137-6951/com.news.daily I/dalvikvm﹕ | group="main" sCount=0 dsCount=0 obj=0x419dc710 self=0x419c60f0
06-08 18:17:05.550    5137-6951/com.news.daily I/dalvikvm﹕ | sysTid=5137 nice=0 sched=0/0 cgrp=apps handle=1074810876
06-08 18:17:05.550    5137-6951/com.news.daily I/dalvikvm﹕ | state=S schedstat=( 3242900256 1453466203 12922 ) utm=238 stm=86 core=3
06-08 18:17:05.560    5137-6951/com.news.daily I/dalvikvm﹕ #00  pc 0001c6ec  /system/lib/libc.so (epoll_wait+12)
06-08 18:17:05.560    5137-6951/com.news.daily I/dalvikvm﹕ #01  pc 000153f1  /system/lib/libutils.so (android::Looper::pollInner(int)+92)
06-08 18:17:05.560    5137-6951/com.news.daily I/dalvikvm﹕ #02  pc 00015615  /system/lib/libutils.so (android::Looper::pollOnce(int, int*, int*, void**)+92)
06-08 18:17:05.560    5137-6951/com.news.daily I/dalvikvm﹕ #03  pc 000729ed  /system/lib/libandroid_runtime.so (android::NativeMessageQueue::pollOnce(_JNIEnv*, int)+22)
06-08 18:17:05.560    5137-6951/com.news.daily I/dalvikvm﹕ #04  pc 00020c0c  /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmPlatformInvoke+112)
06-08 18:17:05.560    5137-6951/com.news.daily I/dalvikvm﹕ #05  pc 0005178b  /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmCallJNIMethod(unsigned int const*, JValue*, Method const*, Thread*)+398)
06-08 18:17:05.560    5137-6951/com.news.daily I/dalvikvm﹕ #06  pc 00000214  /dev/ashmem/dalvik-jit-code-cache (deleted)
06-08 18:17:05.560    5137-6951/com.news.daily I/dalvikvm﹕ at android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce(Native Method)
06-08 18:17:05.560    5137-6951/com.news.daily I/dalvikvm﹕ at android.os.MessageQueue.next(MessageQueue.java:132)
06-08 18:17:05.560    5137-6951/com.news.daily I/dalvikvm﹕ at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:124)
06-08 18:17:05.560    5137-6951/com.news.daily I/dalvikvm﹕ at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5450)
06-08 18:17:05.560    5137-6951/com.news.daily I/dalvikvm﹕ at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-08 18:17:05.560    5137-6951/com.news.daily I/dalvikvm﹕ at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
06-08 18:17:05.560    5137-6951/com.news.daily I/dalvikvm﹕ at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1187)
06-08 18:17:05.560    5137-6951/com.news.daily I/dalvikvm﹕ at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1003)
06-08 18:17:05.560    5137-6951/com.news.daily I/dalvikvm﹕ at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
06-08 18:17:05.560    5137-6951/com.news.daily I/dalvikvm﹕ [ 06-08 18:17:05.560  5137: 6951 I/dalvikvm ]
"AsyncTask #10" prio=5 tid=41 WAIT
```

Comment: Instead of IllegalStateException post stack with exception source (line, etc)

Comment: @dasar i added the exception stack, thx.

Comment: Why don't you ask Picasso to load your images in the ui thread? It will make requests in background for you... Are you in an activity?

Comment: @Médéric i have a HTML5 template built in my app, and i load the template with WebView and render the json data (news text and images' urls)  provided by the activity, so all the news data (news text and images) are managed by WebView, and i use shouldInterceptRequest method to intercept image request to manage images cache by myself instead of WebView.

Answer (score 2):

> The get() method allows you to use a background thread to retrieve the
>   image you want directly. No need for Target.
>
> Currently by invoking into() with this workaround there was always a
>   chance a background thread was used to fetch your image on the target.
>
> It was a mistake from Picasso to allow external callers to invoke
>   into() other than the main thread. Those methods deal with view
>   recycling and canceling without synchronization, hence in Picasso 2.3
>   we added the checks.
>   [From official discussion](https://github.com/square/picasso/issues/524)

So you can use `get()` method instead of `into()` which MUST be called only from UI thread. You can use [OkHttp](http://square.github.io/okhttp/) as http client for Picasso because it has built in cache. Also you can override cache rules by intercepting queries in OkHttp. This two libraries play well together.

Comment: Because shouldInterceptRequest method works in a non-UI thread, so if Picasso supports external callers off the main thread, my problems will be solved.

Comment: You just have to use get() api instead of into()

Comment: thanks @dasar,  i should use get() api, but i also need a thread pool to manage get() operation, because we shouldn't block the thread shouldInterceptRequest  works on.

Answer (score 1):

Here's the solution I ended up with after combining @Xiaozou's example and the suggestions from @dasar:

```
webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    @Override
    public WebResourceResponse shouldInterceptRequest(WebView view, String url) {
        final String mime = URLConnection.guessContentTypeFromName(url);
        if (mime == null || !mime.startsWith("image")) {
            return super.shouldInterceptRequest(view, url);
        }
        try {
            final Bitmap image = Picasso.with(context).load(url).get();
            ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            if (mime.endsWith("jpeg")) {
                image.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, out);
            } else if (mime.endsWith("png")) {
                image.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, out);
            } else {
                return super.shouldInterceptRequest(view, url);
            }
            InputStream in = new ByteArrayInputStream(out.toByteArray());
            return new WebResourceResponse(mime, "UTF-8", in);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Unable to load image", e);
            return super.shouldInterceptRequest(view, url);
        }
    }
});
```

I didn't use `PipedOutputStream` because the request would just terminate inside the `Bitmap.compress` calls and not throw any errors.